# How can I find the volume of intersection between two cubes?

Tags: intersection-theory

How can I find the volume of the intersection of two cubes aligned to the axis? The cubes can have different sizes and positions. (I add a picture to show a simple example case of two cubes)

After deep research, I am quite sure that does not exist a specific function in Unity to use for this purpose, the only way to work out this problem is mathematical logic. For example, my first idea was:

1)To find the 8 vertexes of the cube"intersection" (B in image).

2)Try to build a new cube with this vertex.

3)Find the size and volume of cube "intersection".

Unity permits to find:

A) the centre of each primary cube (A in the image) with "Bounds.centre";

B) the extents of each primary cube (A in the image) from the centre of the cube (half of the size of the Bounds) with "Bounds.extents".

documentation avaible here:https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html

However, I can't find a way to have the vertex of each cube. And, secondly, a logical function that can find what 8 of 16 vertexes found are the right vertex to use to build the cube"Intersection" from their coordinates.

Have u got any help or suggest?

Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORITd.png)

Comment: Are the edges of one cube in the same direction as those of the other, as per your image? That's a very easy special case. Or if you need the general case, would Monte Carlo be fast enough for your purposes?

Comment: @J.G. All the cubes are aligned to the axis, so YES the edges of one cube are in the same direction as those of the other. 
Having established this:
1. what is "Monte Carlo"? 2. Is it valid also in my axis aligned case?

Comment: In that case all you need is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556170/finding-shared-volume-of-two-overlapping-cuboids). Monte Carlo would address this case, as well as others, but it's slow. [Basically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method), you assume the proportion of cube 1 inside cube 2 is the proportion of random points from cube 1 that are in cube 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every prism  $a$ paralel to the axis is characterized by three intervals, one in each coordinate, let them be $a_x,a_y$ and $a_z$. The interval $a_x$ corresponds to the values of $x$ that the points in the prism can take.

If you intersect $a$ with another prism $b$ that corresponds to the intervals $b_x,b_y,b_z$ then you get a prism, the prism that corresponds to the intervals $a_x\cap b_x, a_y\cap b_y, a_z\cap b_z$.

So you just need to calculate the lengths of those intervals and multiply them together.